# Python Autocompletion in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

How can I add a colon automatically at the end of "def", "for" and "if" statements in Python for Visual Studio Code just like in Spyder?

Comment: I kind of think that this question should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use code snippets to insert code with the colon included. Otherwise you will need to create an extension which implements formatting-on-type to do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

#### Switching from PyCharm to VSCode, I have finally found [PyColonize](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fertigt.pycolonize)

[image: Showcase]

#### It adds these shortcuts:

- `Shift` + `Enter` — Insert colon at the end of line and continue on the same line
- `Ctrl`/`CMD` + `Enter` — Insert colon at the end of line and continue on the new line
- `Ctrl`/`CMD` + `Alt` + `Enter` — Insert colon and stay at the same position

**By default shortcut will work only with Python files.** If you want to mimic this behaviour in other languages as well, but without a colon:

1. Open `keybindings.json` (`Ctrl`/`CMD` + `Shift` + `P`, type `>Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`)
2. Insert the following:

```
      {
        "key": "cmd+enter",
        "command": "editor.action.insertLineAfter",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && editorLangId != 'python'"
      }
```

#### For semicolons, see [colonize](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vmsynkov.colonize)

##### If you're switching to VSCode from PyCharm, take a look at [pycharm-to-vscode-transition](https://github.com/Bobronium/pycharm-to-vscode-transition/) repository I've created to help smoothen such transition

Answer (score -1):

go to extensions and search for pylint, then install pylint extension